# Google gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn().get() is always false when multiple google accounts

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I am having a weird problem with google gapi auth. For some reason, the value for `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn().get()` is always returning false. This is my setup:

```
gapi.load("auth2", initAuth2);

initAuth2(){
    gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: "xxxxx-yyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      hosted_domain: "domain.com",
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200",
      ux_mode: "redirect",
    }).then(performAuth, error=>{
      console.error(`Error initiating gapi auth2: ${error.details}`);
    });
}

performAuth(googleAuth){
    const isSignedIn = googleAuth.isSignedIn.get();
    if(!isSignedIn){
      googleAuth.signIn();
      return;
    }
    const user = googleAuth.currentUser.get();
    console.log(user);
}
```

I have two google workspace accounts sign in the same chrome profile. When I run this script, I get the prompt to select an account. No matter which one I choose, the flow just keeps looping. The reason for that is that the line `const isSignedIn = googleAuth.isSignedIn.get();` is always returning false.

Things I've tried so far:

1. I thought that maybe the client_id was corrupted so I generated a new one. Same behaviour.
2. I though the GCP project was corrupted, so I created a new project with new credentials. Same behaviour.
3. Thought there was an issue with cookies, so I deleted and clear cookies and history. Same behaviour.
4. Thought is was related only to localhost so I deployed to the web. Same behaviour.

If I change the init options from `ux_mode: "redirect"` to `ux_mode: "prompt"`. It works. However, that is not the desired experience. Also, if I only have one google workspace in the chrome profile, it works. Even more interesting... if I use a client id from an older project... it works! The problem is that the consent screen shows the wrong app name.

I know this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563824/gapi-auth2-getauthinstance-issignedin-get-is-always-false-when-chrome-browse), however I feel it's different because none of the above troubleshooting works. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

There is a case for the exact same problem [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/361), it is most likely a bug in the api set